# Solving non linear PDE using Charpit's equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$(y+zq)^2=z^2(1+p^2+q^2)$.

How to find the complete integral of the given pde by using Charpit's equations ?

Charpit's equations are:

$$ \frac{dx}{2pz^2}=\frac{dy}{2qz^2-2z(y+zq)}=\frac{dz}{2p^2z^2-2qz(y+zq)}=\frac{dp}{-2pz(1+p^2+q^2)}=\frac{dq}{2(y+zq)-2qz(1+p^2+q^2)} $$

Comment: That short enough of an equation to type set in mathjax.  Surround the equation in dollar signs (one on each end, or two on each end).  Use parentheses like normal; for exponents, e.g. $x^2$, use `x^2`

Comment: Take a look at the formatting I just used with the help you contributed. (Click edit the lower left of the question (immediately below the tag pde.)

Comment: (dp/p-dq/q)    and dx/z=dp/(1+p2+q2) etc however i am unable to integrate it

Answer (score 0):

Let $u:=z^2$, so that $z=\pm\sqrt{u}$ and $(p,q)=(z_x,z_y)=\left(\pm\frac{u_x}{2\sqrt{u}},\pm\frac{u_y}{2\sqrt{u}}\right)=:\left(\frac{P}{2z},\frac{Q}{2z}\right)$. In terms of the new variables $u, P,$ and $Q$, the PDE reads
$$
\left(y+\frac{Q}{2}\right)^2=u+\frac{P^2+Q^2}{4}
\implies y^2+Qy-u-\frac{P^2}{4}=0. \tag{1}
$$
The Charpit's equations corresponding to $(1)$ are
$$
\frac{dx}{-\frac{P}{2}}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dP}{P}=\frac{dQ}{-2y}=\frac{du}{-\frac{P^2}{2}+Qy}, \tag{2}
$$
from which follow
$$
P=-2(x+a)\quad\text{and}\quad Q=-2(y+b), \tag{3}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants.

From $(2)$ it also follows that $du=Pdx+Qdy$; combined with $(3)$, it yields
$$
u=-(x+a)^2-(y+b)^2+c. \tag{4}
$$
To determine the the constant $c$, we substitute $(3)$ and $(4)$ in $(1)$; the result is $c=b^2$. Therefore, the complete integral of the original PDE is the family of spheres
$$
(x+a)^2+(y+b)^2+z^2=b^2. \tag{5}
$$